# ROOT cern install error

Tags: installation, package, root-framework

I'm trying to install ROOT (from cern) and I have a problem. This is the error that I have after make comand.

```
bin/rootcling: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfow.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I resolve this? I looked for a libtinfow package but seems it doen't exist!

Comment: can you add some more information? e.g. in which part of the buildprocess does this happen (enable printing the executed commands with `cmake -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON`). Were there errors/warnings when running cmake. Did you enable/disable some components? which operating system are you on?

Comment: the ' -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON ' soved all my problems! I read the error and I fixed it! Thank you!!

Comment: @Pandora: Since you figured out what was wrong here, it would be great if you could answer your own question. Alternatively close your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install ncurses shared lib, and while configuring ncurses before building do:
 ./configure --prefix=/path/to/ncurses --with-termlib --with-shared --enable-widec